# Rails 3- Active_admin and CanCan integration

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan, activeadmin

The title is very explanatory.

How can I integrate active_admin gem with cancan?
I need administrative roles.

Thanks

Comment: I took a short look at the gem and I think you can follow the instructions of cancan. That should do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to follow this [guide](https://gist.github.com/1264060)

Robbie

Answer (score 1):

for a simple case, assuming there are 2 roles:   normal_user , admin,

if you just want to "admin" to access "/admin" (activeadmin's default namespace), while "normal_user" can not, I suggest you take a look a hook method:

```
# config/initializers/active_admin.rb
config.before_filter :check_user_role

# define this method in applicaton_controller.rb
def check_user_role
  redirect_to root_path unless current_user.role == "admin"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Following link is also helpful to set cancan with activeadmin.

https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/wiki/How-to-work-with-cancan

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays there is a gem that do the work: https://github.com/11factory/activeadmin-cancan